# Scrapy not parsing response in make_requests_from_url loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to get scrapy to grab a URL from a message queue, and then scrape that URL. I have the loop going just fine and grabbing the URL from the queue, but it never enters the `parse()` method once it has a url, it just continues to loop (and sometimes the url comes back around even though I've deleted it from the queue...)

While it's running in terminal, if I CTRL+C and force it to end, it enters the `parse()` method and crawls the page, then ends. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

```
class my_Spider(Spider):
        name = "my_spider"
        allowed_domains = ['domain.com']

        def __init__(self):
            super(my_Spider, self).__init__()
            self.url = None

        def start_requests(self):
            while True:
                # Crawl the url from queue
                yield self.make_requests_from_url(self._pop_queue())

        def _pop_queue(self):
            # Grab the url from queue
            return self.queue()

        def queue(self):
            url = None
            while url is None:
                conf = {
                    "sqs-access-key": "",
                    "sqs-secret-key": "",
                    "sqs-queue-name": "crawler",
                    "sqs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "sqs-path": "sqssend"
                }
                # Connect to AWS
                conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(
                    conf.get('sqs-region'),
                    aws_access_key_id=conf.get('sqs-access-key'),
                    aws_secret_access_key=conf.get('sqs-secret-key')
                )
                q = conn.get_queue(conf.get('sqs-queue-name'))
                message = conn.receive_message(q)
                # Didn't get a message back, wait.
                if not message:
                    time.sleep(10)
                    url = None
                else:
                    url = message
            if url is not None:
                message = url[0]
                message_body = str(message.get_body())
                message.delete()
                self.url = message_body
                return self.url

        def parse(self, response):
            ...
            yield item
```

Updated from comments:

```
def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        # Crawl the url from queue
        queue = self._pop_queue()
        self.logger.error(queue)
        if queue is None:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
        url = queue
        if url:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
```

Removed the `while url is None:` loop, but still get the same problem.

Comment: Could you provide code where you call `parse` mehtod?

Comment: Well, I don't, scrapy does. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?url#scrapy.spiders.Spider.make_requests_from_url Are you familiar with how scrapy works?

Comment: problem seems to be `def queue(self):` function , you are not returning anything from functions when `URL is None`and hence code hangs in that loop and only resume when you `cancel "CTRL+C"`current request with empty URL

Comment: Updated my question @MrPandav no change.

Comment: I am thinking forever Requesting start url and making request from if is not suiting with scrapy engine ... can you try with limited set of urls list static and then `for url in urls:  yield self.make_request_from_url(url)` and see if that works

Comment: It does, but I need the URLs organically, from the message queue. I don't know the urls beforehand, just the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would I be right to assume that if this works:

```
import scrapy
import random

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__()
        self.url = None

    def start_requests(self):
        while True:
            # Crawl the url from queue
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(self._pop_queue())

    def _pop_queue(self):
        # Grab the url from queue
        return self.queue()

    def queue(self):
        return 'http://www.example.com/?{}'.format(random.randint(0,100000))

    def parse(self, response):
        print "Successfully parsed!"
```

Then your code should work as well, unless:

- There's a problem with `allowed_domains` and your queue actually returns URLs outside it
- There's a problem with your `queue()` function and/or the data it produces e.g. it returns arrays or it blocks indefinitely or something like that

Note also that the `boto` library is blocking and not Twisted/asynchronous. In order to not block scrapy while using it, you will have to use a Twisted-compatible library like [txsqs](https://github.com/mtak/txsqs). Alternatively you might want to run `boto` calls in a separate thread with [deferToThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#deferToThread).

After your follow up question in Scrapy list, I believe that you have to understand that your code is quite far from functional and this makes it as much as generic Boto/SQS question as Scrapy question. Anyway - here's an average functional solution.

I've created and AWS SQS with this properties:

[image]

Then gave it some overly broad permissions:

[image]

Now I'm able to submit messages in the queue with AWS CLi like this:

```
$ aws --region eu-west-1 sqs send-message --queue-url "https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/123412341234/my_queue" --message-body 'url:https://stackoverflow.com'
```

For some weird reason - I think that when I was setting `--message-body` to a URL it was actually downloading the page and sending the result as message body(!) Not sure - don't have time to confirm this, but interesting. Anyway.

Here's a proper'ish Spider code. As I said before, `boto` is blocking API which is bad. In this implementation I call its API just once from `start_requests()` and then only when the spider is `idle` on the `spider_idle()` callback. At that point, because the spider is `idle`, the fact that `boto` is blocking doesn't pose much of a problem. While I pull URLs from SQS, I pull as many as possible with the `while` loop (you could put a limit there if you don't want to consume e.g. more than 500 at a time) in order to have to call the blocking API as rarely as possible. Notice also the call to `conn.delete_message_batch()` which actually removes messages from the queue (otherwise they just stay there for ever) and the `queue.set_message_class(boto.sqs.message.RawMessage)` that avoids [this](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2965) problem.

Overall this might be an ok solution for your level of requirements.

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from scrapy import signals
import boto.sqs

from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider

class CPU_Z(Spider):
    name = "cpuz"
    allowed_domains = ['http://valid.x86.fr']

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(CPU_Z, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
        return spider

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CPU_Z, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        conf = {
            "sqs-access-key": "AK????????????????",
            "sqs-secret-key": "AB????????????????????????????????",
            "sqs-queue-name": "my_queue",
            "sqs-region": "eu-west-1",
        }
        self.conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(
            conf.get('sqs-region'),
            aws_access_key_id=conf.get('sqs-access-key'),
            aws_secret_access_key=conf.get('sqs-secret-key')
        )
        self.queue = self.conn.get_queue(conf.get('sqs-queue-name'))
        assert self.queue
        self.queue.set_message_class(boto.sqs.message.RawMessage)

    def _get_some_urs_from_sqs(self):
        while True:
            messages = self.conn.receive_message(self.queue, number_messages=10)

            if not messages:
                break

            for message in messages:
                body = message.get_body()
                if body[:4] == 'url:':
                    url = body[4:]
                    yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

            self.conn.delete_message_batch(self.queue, messages)

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        for request in self._get_some_urs_from_sqs():
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(request, self)

        raise DontCloseSpider()

    def start_requests(self):
        for request in self._get_some_urs_from_sqs():
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "freq_clock": response.url
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Answer! I wouldn't have thought of using the idle event in this way. Is it possible to use the tzsqs library if you were running things without the idle handler? I tried it out and it doesn't seem like the start_requests method works with a generator that returns deferred objects.